# ASP.Net Dropdownlist ListItem (Enabled=false) not showing in page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist` in aspx called `ddlService`.

I want to added the listitems from behind.

When I add, I will create them in order of Title and items underneath like..

```
Title1
Item1
Item2
Title2
Item1
Item2
```

Titles should not be able to click. Only Items should be able to click.

```
ListItem tempServicesItem = new ListItem();
tempServicesItem.Text = tempTitle;
tempServicesItem.Value = tempTitle;
tempServicesItem.Enabled = false;     
ddlServices.Items.Add(tempServicesItem);
tempServicesItem = new ListItem();
tempServicesItem.Text = tempItem;
tempServicesItem.Value = tempItem;                                                        
ddlServices.Items.Add(tempServicesItem);
```

The problem I encountered is The `ListItems` with (`Enabled=false`) are not appearing in aspx.

When I change it to (`Enabled=true`), it is appearing.

I must have missed out something. Can anyone point out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. (Not tested)

```
tempServicesItem.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Yes, I just found out that also. Thanks anyway. For more reference,http://forums.asp.net/t/1132654.aspx (READ till the end)

Comment: I found a hiccup though. If i select the one of the values and page is refreshed. After that, the attributes are gone.

Comment: I have a workaround for myself. That would be give the `value` of the `Titles` some unique name like `Title_Unclickable`. Then on every `page_load` of `(IsPostBack)` loop the dropdownlist and apply that `disable` attributes to all those items with the value I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx) says

> You cannot use this property to disable a ListItem control in a
>   DropDownList control or ListBox control.

I think you need to set the "disabled" attribute which corresponds to the HTML markup for the [option](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) element

```
tempServicesItem.Attributes["disabled"] = "true";
```